# How to run db2pd -hadr in batch mode

Tags: db2, command-line, db2-9.7

I am trying to automate some things on DB2 and would like to use a batch file to do this. I create the following batch file `test.bat`:

```
db2cmd - -w "db2 -tvf test.db2"
```

I then try to do two commands in the `test.db2` script, which work together in the CLP interactive mode:

```
!set db2instance=INST1;
!db2pd -db MYDB -hadr;
```

I then get the following output:

> Database MYDB not activated on database partition 0.
>   Option -hadr requires -db  or -alldbs option and active database.

I'm using DB2 9.7 LUW on Windows 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this using two batch files:

```
test1.bat
------------------------------------------------------------------------
db2cmd -c -i -w "test2.bat"
PAUSE

test2.bat
------------------------------------------------------------------------
set db2instance=INST1
db2pd -db MYDB -hadr
```

This is effectively the same as running in interactive mode but if anybody has a way to do this using only one batch file please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Both commands in `test.db` are Windows commands, you don't need the CLP to run them. Try:

```sh
db2cmd -w "set db2instance=INST1 & 
db2pd -db MYDB -hadr"
```

Your original attempt did not work you invoked Windows commands from the DB2 CLP: The first one created a new environment and set the `DB2INSTANCE` variable in it, then quit, which destroyed that environment. The second command created yet another environment, in which `DB2INSTANCE` was not set (or set to a wrong value), so `db2pd` could not see the database. - [mustaccio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/23721/mustaccio)

In NT's batch files `command1 & command2` means "run command2 after command1 finishes, even if command1 fails". If you have lots of commands to chain together you can place them on separate lines; use `^` at the end of each line to escape the newline character and don't forget to eventually close the `"` (`^` is the escape character in NT's batch files ... at least that's what I vaguely recall from my days administering Windows). - [dave-jones](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/61684/dave-jones)